# Retain data in grid

Tags: mvcgrid.net

I want my MVCGrid.net grid to fetch new data only when the user clicks the refresh button that I have added to my view.

If the user goes to a new page in the pagination, sorts, or filters, I don't want the grid to fetch new data.  I just want it to use the data that already exists in the grid.

Is this possible?  We were thinking that maybe we could store the items in a session variable and get the existing data from that, but the GridContext that is a parameter for WithRetrieveDataMethod has an HttpContext that is null when we come back through on a new page, sort, or filter.

Thanks!